# Reuse App ID with freshly created Developer Team

Tags: ios-appstore, app-store-connect, developer-program

I have two apps on one Developer account which have been tested through TestFlight feature, but never released.

Now, the customer accidentally decided to release them via absolutely new Developer Team. I'm Admin in both of teams, and have email/password access for Team Agent of new account.

As far as I know, you can delete/transfer your apps if you ever released it to the AppStore. But it's not our case. Also, I can't change App's Bundle ID due to existing uploads to it with Bundle ID being linked. Since these apps using their App IDs, I can't remove them in the Member Center. And moreover, I can't use them in new account.

I know we could change App ID, but it's linked to a bunch of various 3rd-parties to which I don't have an access, and this would take sufficient time to retrieve the credentials.

1. Is there any option for me to solve it having only what I got?
2. Or will it be enough if I catch email/password for Team Agent of current team?
3. If not, then only way is to first release the app under current account and after transfer it to new one?
4. Or I can't do anything but use different Bundle ID?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Release your app in the App Store with the old account.
2. The minute it is released (you can specify the date), you change the status to 'Developer Rejected'
3. Transfer your app to the new account.

From [Apple Developer documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Chapters/TransferringAndDeletingApps.html):

> Before you transfer an app to another developer, ensure you’ve met the
>   following criteria:
>
> - Make sure your accounts aren’t in a pending or changing state.
> - Make sure the app uses only technology and content that can be transferred.
> - No version of the app can use an iCloud entitlement.
> - No version of the app can use a Passbook entitlement.
> - The app can’t offer (or have previously offered) in-app purchase subscriptions: auto-renewable, free, or non-renewing.
> - The App must have had **at least one version** that has been **released** to the App Store.
>
> Make sure the app and any in-app purchase products it offers have a
>   status that supports transfers. The app status can be one of the following:
>
> - Ready for Sale
> - Prepare for Submission
> - Developer Removed From Sale
> - Invalid Binary
> - Developer Rejected
> - Rejected

Comment: What will happen to push notifications then? App is built with Amazon Services, including SNS. If I transfer an app, will they work stable? Should I re-create push notification certificates for next builds?

Comment: It uses the same certificates right? In that case it shouldn't be a problem.